# Scriptella: get error codes and messages within onerror tag

Tags: mysql, etl, scriptella

Using Scriptella ETL, i recently came to know about the onerror tag. It is working fine,but I want to make a generic code which inserts the code and the message into the database whenever any error occurs.

I am using it like this:

```
 <onerror codes="42604,42617,42000,1366" >
        INSERT INTO demo_travel.test_log(Time_Now, ErrorName) values (    sysdate(),'eeuhue');
  </onerror>
```

Which is working, but I want something like this:

```
 <onerror  >
        INSERT INTO demo_travel.test_log(Time_Now, ErrorName,ErrorMSG) values (    sysdate(),Error.code, error.msg);
  </onerror>
```

Comment: store `Error.code` string in some variable then pass in insert query

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to achieve that. onerror was based on the assumption that a developer knows an error he is dealing with. But I do agree this has to be improved. The problem was partially addressed in a [Feature request: Allow different connection-id in onerror element](http://javaforge.com/issue/54586).

So for 1.1 or earlier versions, this is not possible. For a [current development snapshot of 1.2](http://javaforge.com/displayDocument/scriptella-1.2-SNAPSHOT.zip?doc_id=222665), this information can be inferred from the "error" variable as explained in the [ticket](http://javaforge.com/issue/54586). I've also created a [subticket](http://javaforge.com/issue/186240) to expose additional properties of the error.